# ¿Cómo desactivar la comprobación de tipos en typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, importación

Necesito que `typeScript` ignore que un objeto tenga o no 'x propiedad'.
Estoy migrando a `typeScript` y me esta dando ese error. No he encontrado un flag para el `tsConfig` que permita ignorarlo.
Por ejemplo: creo un objeto y le cargo las propiedades por parámetro cuando se los mando pero parece no permitirlo `typeScript`.
el 'append' pertenece a la libreria 'd3.js' y el objeto '$el' se lo estoy enviando cargado desde otra clase cuando se ejecuta.

```
$el.append('rect')
```

Basicamente recibe los parametros y los carga pero typeScript me genera error al no encontrarlos como import o en el archivo mismo declarado.

Adjunto cap:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Declara los objetos con la palabra del demonio `any`. Por ejemplo: `let $el : any = {}`. Con esto pierde todo el sentido trabajar en `typescript`, pero es la respuesta a lo que preguntas. También puedes marcar ese archivo con `// @ts-nocheck` al inicio para deshabilitar el check.

Comment: Gracias, funciono.
¿Por que pierde sentido? como se tendria que trabajar en typeScript. Entiendo que si tengo que andar poniendole "any" a modo de parche no sea lo mejor pero es que se lo mando desde otro objeto. Es una utilidad justo esa , se llama "anotacion" y algunos charts la usan, que son desde donde la suelo invocar.

Comment: La idea de typescript es conocer siempre la forma que tendrán tus objetos y establecer buenas prácticas. Lo ideal, es declarar interfaces que definan la forma que tendrán tus objetos, y especificar los tipos cuando los declaras. No entiendo el uso de "typescript" en tu código porque la verdad haces cosas bien raras. Ej: `colorFn` la declaras que no recibe argumentos y luego  la llamas con dos argumentos `colorFn(d,range)`, `$el` es cuando lo declaras es un objeto y luego ¿Se convierte en array en algún momento :  `$el.append`?

Comment: Deberías darle una revisión a los conceptos básicos de typescript y la forma de trabajar. Revisar los tipos básicos del DOM que son super importantes y como declarar tus propias interfaces.

Comment: Por cierto, `typescript`, tiene librerías que definen los tipos de [`d3.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3). Instálatelas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desactivar la comprobación de tipos en `typescript` es una mala práctica y **NO** debe realizarse a menos que no haya alternativas.

No obstante, para hacerlo tienes varias opciones:

1. Para desactivar el chequeo de tipos en solamente una línea en específico, agrega antes de la línea deseada el comentario:

```
// @ts-ignore
```

2. Para desactivar el chequeo en un objeto específico, declara el objeto como tipo `any`:

```
let $el : any = {}
```

3. Para desactivar el chequeo de tipos completamente en el archivo actual, agrega un comentario al inicio del archivo con el contenido:

```
// @ts-nocheck
```

Comment: Entiendo, pero pocos leen los comentarios, aparte del OP. Toma en cuenta que tu respuesta será vista por muchos otros desarrolladores que busquen una solución a un problema parecido. Tal vez si das un énfasis en tu respuesta y no sólo en los comentarios, sería una respuesta mucho más completa. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Incluir la definición de tipos de `d3` no iba a solucionar sus problemas. Si te das cuenta, no tiene mucho dominio de `typescript` cuando declara una función sin parámetros y la llama con dos parámetros y NUNCA especifica un solo tipo en su archivo.  No obstante añadí tu sugerencia, pero la respuesta responde perfectamente a la pregunta. Con un poco de suerte, la gente no anda por ahí desactivando el tipado.

Comment: Tu respuesta efectivamente responde la pregunta del OP, de eso no cabe duda, pero enfatizar que es una mala práctica hace tu respuesta mucho más completa (enriquecedora) de cara al conocimiento compartido, ese es el motivo de mi comentario inicial, que procedo a eliminar, ya que he logrado mi cometido. Saludos

Comment: hey hey, esta bien por mi. Mejor que me aclaren que no lo haga por su puesto.
Se recontra agradece.
Se conceptos básicos de ts y estoy estudiandolo (si pasan fuentes ademas de la documentacion oficial sobre TS seria buenisimo) . 
En cuanto al codigo en realidad es JS. Asi como esta se le cambio la terminacion a .ts y empecé a ver que tal despues de configurar el config.ts